# Как после преобразований из строки в объект в LOCALSTORAGE, этот объект поместить в массив и после обновления страницы чтобы уже находился там?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localstorage

у меня есть массив объектов

```
var tasks = [{
        name: "Задача № 1",
        selectedProject: 'select project',
        dateBegin: new Date('07 24, 2016 19:58:49'),
        dateFinish: new Date('07 24, 2016 19:58:59')
      }, {
        name: "Задача № 2",
        selectedProject: 'timer',
        dateBegin: new Date('07 25, 2016 19:58:30'),
        dateFinish: new Date('07 25, 2016 19:59:15')
      }]
```

Надо чтобы после заполнения некоторых полей, объект сохранялся в LocalStorage.
Как после этого достать объект из `LocalStorage`  поместить в массив, и чтобы после обновления показывался пользователю?

делаю так:

```
localStorage.setItem("tasks", serialTask);
var serialTask = JSON.stringify(tasks); 
var returnTask = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
```

остается только добавить новый объект в массив tasks и чтобы после обновления выводилось пользователю, помогите!

код таблицы

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Задача </th>
            <th> Проэкт </th>
            <th> Быстрый старт </th>
            <th> Потраченное время на задачу </th>
            <th> Время работы </th>
            <th> Дата завершения проекта </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in tasks track by $index">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.selectedProject}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn-quickStart" ng-click="quickStart(item)"></button></td>
            <td>{{dateDifference(item.dateBegin, item.dateFinish)}}</td>
            <td>{{item.dateBegin.toLocaleTimeString()}} - {{item.dateFinish.toLocaleTimeString()}} </td>
            <td>{{item.dateFinish.toLocaleDateString()}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

код контроллера

```
var timerApp = angular.module('timerApp', ['LocalStorageModule','ngStorage']);
timerApp.controller("timerController", function($scope, $timeout,localStorageService) {


    var newTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));


    var clocktimer;
    $scope.timer = function() {
        $scope.clock = $scope.dateDifference($scope.currentTask.dateBegin, new Date());
        clocktimer = $timeout($scope.timer, 1000);

    }

    $scope.buttonText = "Start";

    $scope.startOrStop = function() {
        if ($scope.currentTask.dateBegin == undefined) {
            $scope.start();
        } else {
            $scope.stop();
        }

    };
    $scope.tasks = newTasks ;
    $scope.project = [{
        project: "select project"
    }, {
        project: "timer"
    }, {
        project: "timer1"
    }, {
        project: "timer2"
    }];
    $scope.currentTask = {
        name: '',
        selectedProject: 'select project',
        dateFinish: ''
    };

    $scope.start = function() {
        var dateBegin = new Date();
        $scope.currentTask.dateBegin = dateBegin;
        $scope.style = {
            background: 'red'
        };
        $scope.buttonText = "Stop";
        $scope.timer();
        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));

    }

    $scope.stop = function() {
        var dateFinish = new Date();
        $scope.currentTask.dateFinish = dateFinish;
        $scope.tasks.push($scope.currentTask);
        $timeout.cancel(clocktimer);
        $scope.clock = '00:00:00';
        $scope.tasks.sort(tasksCompare);
        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
        $scope.currentTask = {};
        $scope.style = {
            background: '#11dc51'
        }
        $scope.buttonText = "Start";
    }


    $scope.dateDifference = function(dateBegin, dateFinish) {
        var dateDifference = ((Math.floor((dateFinish) / 1000)) - (Math.floor((dateBegin) / 1000)));
        var seconds = dateDifference % 60;
        dateDifference -= seconds;
        dateDifference = Math.floor(dateDifference / 60);
        var minutes = dateDifference % 60;
        dateDifference -= minutes;
        dateDifference = Math.floor(dateDifference / 60);
        var hours = dateDifference % 60;
        if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;
        dateDifference = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        return dateDifference;
    }

    $scope.quickStart = function(tasks) {
        if ($scope.currentTask.dateBegin !== undefined) {
            $scope.stop();
        }
        $scope.start();
        $scope.currentTask.name = tasks.name;
        $scope.currentTask.selectedProject = tasks.selectedProject;
    }

    function tasksCompare(a, b) {
        var r = 0;
        if (a.dateFinish > b.dateFinish) {
            r = -1;
        }
        if (a.dateFinish < b.dateFinish) {
            r = 1;
        }
        return r;
    }

});
```

[image: осталась проблема с dateDifference]

Comment: что за _LocalStorageModule_?

Comment: $Grundy, то старые мои разработки а вообще https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: стоит привести пример в порядок и удалить старые наработки/не используемый код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понял код и возникающие трудности. Уточните, на каком этапе у вас возникают проблемы?

Ваш пример кода непонятен, три какие-то несвязанные строки...

Так или иначе, ниже пример как записать-достать-изменить-записать.

```
//исходный массив
var tasks = [{
    name: "Задача № 1",
    selectedProject: 'select project',
    dateBegin: new Date('07 24, 2016 19:58:49'),
    dateFinish: new Date('07 24, 2016 19:58:59')
  }, {
    name: "Задача № 2",
    selectedProject: 'timer',
    dateBegin: new Date('07 25, 2016 19:58:30'),
    dateFinish: new Date('07 25, 2016 19:59:15')
}];

//сохраняем в localStorage
localStorage.setItem("tasks", tasks); 

//достаем из localStorage после перезагрузки страницы
var returnTask = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));

//изменяем данные и сохраняем обратно
returnTask[1]['selectedProject'] = "newProject"; 
localStorage.setItem("tasks", returnTask);
```

**UPD**

Решение проблемы вывода строковой даты в таблице.

На самом деле, все, вероятно, просто и никакие условия ставить самому не придется. Попробуйте исправить код шаблона на следующий:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Задача </th>
            <th> Проэкт </th>
            <th> Быстрый старт </th>
            <th> Потраченное время на задачу </th>
            <th> Время работы </th>
            <th> Дата завершения проекта </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in tasks track by $index">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.selectedProject}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn-quickStart" ng-click="quickStart(item)"></button></td>
            <td>{{dateDifference(item.dateBegin, item.dateFinish)}}</td>
            <td>{{item.dateBegin|date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}} - {{item.dateFinish|date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}} </td>
            <td>{{item.dateFinish|date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Думаю, шаблонизатор сам разберется, строка там или объект даты. Если не получится - пишите, попробуем по-другому.

Comment: Изначально при загрузке страницы эти 2 объекта,которые лежат в массиве, показываются пользователю в виде заполненной таблички.
 После действий пользователя( заполнения полей) и нажатии на кнопку, создается новый объект, который помещается в массив tasks, однако после перезагрузки страницы все исчезает, поэтому мне надо, чтобы новый объект сохранялся в массиве, а при обновлении страницы, показывался массив tasks уже с новым объектом

Comment: @Дмитрий так а в чем проблема? Сохраняйте новый tasks после изменений пользователя в localStorage. На загрузке страницы доставайте оттуда и отрисовывайте в табличке. На каком именно этапе сложности?

Comment: на этапе достать новый таск и отрисовать...

Comment: @Дмитрий как достать - код выше. буквально ctrl+c - ctrl+v. А как отрисовать - это уже вам виднее, вы нам не рассказывали о структуре таблицы и не показывали код, который ее отрисовывает. Добавьте в вопрос код таблицы или ко, который ее отрисовывает.

Comment: я понял в чем проблема, у меня теперь все достается и отрисовывается, но есть одно "но", как парсить даты, веди Json.parse, не понимает,что дата это дата и выдает строкой, из-за этого в таблице значения NUL

Comment: нужно идти туда, где отрисовываются ячейки таблицы с датами и добавить там проверку. Если имеем не дату, а строку - выполнить new Date(str)

Comment: скинул код таблицы и контроллера, помогите написать чтобы время парсировалась а то не пойму как и где

Comment: @Дмитрий добавил в ответ вариант исправления

Comment: добавил фото, того,что получилось! Осталась проблема с <td>{{dateDifference(item.dateBegin, item.dateFinish)}}</td>

Comment: По аналогии добавьте фильтр |date(..). Я в ответе добавил.

Comment: данный фильтр не сработал, на <td>{{dateDifference(item.dateBegin, item.dateFinish)}}, по ходу все таки прийдется парсить дату, может подскажите, как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

мне порекомендовали сделать так?

```
localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks, function(key, value) {
  if(value instanceof Date) {
    return '$ISODate(' + value.toISOString() + ')';
  }
  return value;
}));


var newTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"), function(key, value) {
  if(typeof value !== 'string') {
    return value;
  }
  var m = value.match(/\$ISODate\((.*)\)/);
  if(!m) {
    return value;
  }
  return new Date(m[1]);
});
```